# ReferenceError: JQOTE2_TMPL_EXEC_ERROR is not defined

Tags: jqote

I am using Jqote2 for my project. whenever i try to call a particular lambda by $.jqote , it is saying "ReferenceError: JQOTE2_TMPL_EXEC_ERROR is not defined"

the template corresponding to the lambda is sound and the parameters that i am passing to the lambda are logically and syntactically correct. and i am doing sync ajax call while loading the template therefore no chance of template not loading.

the template i am using is

```
<div class="facet"><h4><%=decodeURI(this.attributes.label)%></h4>
    <%if("true"===decodeURI(this.attributes.autoExpand)){%>
        <ul style="display:block">
    <%}else{%>
        <ul style="display:none">
    <%}%>
    <%=window.createonline.service.FacetService.buildFacet(this.item)%>
</ul></div>
```

I tried moving the elements around,in vain.

What may be the error?
Plz help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this has no answers.
and now,the specs to my project has changed,and this is no longer required.